# How to convert a specific string value taken from a file and convert it into a specific integer value?

Tags: java

After reading a file in and assigning each letter to a specific integer value, how would I then convert the read-in string into the initialized integers as seen below?

```
A = 20
B = 30
C = 40
D = 50
```

The file has the following data:  B D C A C A D B

How do I then convert the letters read in from the file into the numbers?  For example, if I read B in, how would I convert it into 30?

Comment: Use this: **int java.lang.Integer.parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException**

Comment: @Imran:  You don't need to throw the runtime exception.

Comment: @Makoto what if we get a invalid String as input?

Comment: Well, *throwing* the exception won't do you any good...

Comment: @Makoto it seems clear to me that Imran was referring to the docs with his comment.

Comment: Is there any logic behind `30 for B`?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use a Map.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", 20);
map.put("B", 30);
map.put("C", 40);
map.put("D", 50);
```

> The file.txt has the following data: B D C A C A D B

```
String item1 = inputFile.next();
Integer value1 = map.get(item1);  // turns B => 30.
```